# Why is there no link to Flair(TM) on my network SE profile?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flair

I have profiles on a few different SE sites.  These have links to my Flair(TM) in the [stats][bounties][prefs][flair][accounts] menu.

I also have a really nice "network profile" on StackExchange.  But that doesn't have a link to my Flair(TM).

Please, can that link be put on there somehow?  Even if only the combined Flair(TM) is shown that'd be good.

Answer (score 1):

Network profiles have a flair tab now, e.g. here's yours:

https://stackexchange.com/users/504610/danbeale?tab=flair